# What does GXBDTE means in GXBDTE+LiberationSans font?

Tags: pdf, fonts

LiberationSans seems to be installed however when I try to edit my pdf using a pdf editor I have a pop-up that the current font is not available in the system and I can't edit the text with the selected font: GXBDTE+LiberationSans

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a [prefix that indicates the font was subsetted when the PDF was generated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156429/). The PDF contains only the part of (subset of) the LiberationSans font that is used in the document. If your document consisted only of the word "Hello" then the subset would be the glyphs for 'H', 'e', 'l' and 'o'. The other glyphs are left out, saving a bit of space in the resulting file.

Without knowing which PDF editor you're thinking of, it is difficult to tell whether it should be smart enough to find the other glyphs by looking for them on your system.

If you still have the source document, you may be better off editing that instead.